# Android RecycleView AsyncTask loading image

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm making app with photo gallery, and I have RecycleView for displaying this photos. There was lot of problems but I solved many of them. I have added AsyncTask to load photos.

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<File, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private File data = null;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(File... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return load();
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have problem with fast scrolling. I don't want to setImage if we already skipt some photos. 
I found on Android docs this document (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) 
And I want to implement this

```
 if (v.position == position) {
        // If this item hasn't been recycled already, hide the
        // progress and set and show the image
    ...
    }
```

But I don't know what is v.position, how to set it, and what is position and how to get it from RecyclerView. Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't want to setImage if we already skipt some photos*

To achieve this pass refernce of your RecyclerView's LinearLayoutManager and current position to AsyncTask

getLayoutManager()

```
public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView,LinearLayoutManager layoutManager,int viewPosition) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.position = viewPosition;
}
```

In PostExecute do this

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
  if(position >= layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() && position <= layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()){
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

*But I don't know what is v.position, how to set it, and what is position and how to get it from RecyclerView.*

I am not able to understand your question here, but if you mean to store position with view then you can use view.setTag() to store position